# Strange increment in while loop (Assembly 80x86)

Tags: assembly, x86

I wrote a loop that takes an array of 10 digits and concatenates them to one big output string. Though, when it enters my innerloop to check how many characters there are in the string, it counts it way too many times. Any idea on why this is happening?

scoreArray = is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

counter2 ends up with a value of 11 bytes for the first element

```
    while3:
    mov counter2, 0
    mov edx, 0
    dtoa temp2, scoreArray[ebx]   ; store each value in temp2 as string

    add ebx, 4
    cmp ebx, 44
    je endWhile3

        ;problem area
    innerLoop3:
    cmp temp2[edx], 0      ; check to see if there is a space
    je concLoop            ; if there is, jump to concLoop
    inc counter2           ; add another Byte to the total
    inc edx
    jmp innerLoop3

    concLoop:


    ;inc counter2
    mov eax, countTotal
    lea esi, temp2
    lea edi, outString+17+[eax]+1+17
    cld
    mov ecx, counter2
    rep movsb
    add eax, counter2
    mov countTotal, eax
    jmp while3

    endWhile3:
```

Comment: What is dtoa? The problem might be there..

Comment: As a followup to @BlackBear's comment, are you sure `dtoa` is properly terminating the string?

Comment: dtoa takes a double and converter it to an ascii. dtoa (destination), (source). I need to do this because originally the values in my array aren't string.

Comment: If i print out temp2[edx] inside the loop, i get "1" 11 times. Each time it's printed it shifts a little to the left, though.

Comment: I am not sure if inside of the temp2 array are ASCCIs values or not, but the ASCII code for a space is 32 decimal.